# Verify rabbitmq credentials are valid

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'd like to write a simple smoke test that runs after deployment to verify that the RabbitMQ credentials are valid. What's the simplest way to check that rabbitmq username/password/vhost are valid?

*Edit:*  Preferably, check using a bash script. Alternatively, using a Python script.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As you haven't provided any details about language, etc.:

You could simply issue a HTTP GET request to the management api.

```
$ curl -i -u guest:guest http://localhost:15672/api/whoami
```

See [RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.13.1/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html)

Comment: differentiate between `"reason":"Login failed"` and `"reason":"Not management user"` and you can tell if the credentials work even if the user is not an admin

Answer (score 28):

Here's a way to check using Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
from kombu import Connection
host = "localhost"
port = 5672
user = "guest"
password = "guest"
vhost = "/"
url = 'amqp://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(user, password, host, port, vhost)
with Connection(url) as c:
    try:
        c.connect()
    except socket.error:
        raise ValueError("Received socket.error, "
                         "rabbitmq server probably isn't running")
    except IOError:
        raise ValueError("Received IOError, probably bad credentials")
    else:
        print "Credentials are valid"
```

Answer (score 12):

You could try with `rabbitmqctl` as well,

```
rabbitmqctl authenticate_user username password
```

and check the return code in Bash.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 it shows `Error: could not recognise command` and the help about the comment. What are the requirements for the `authenticate_user` command?

Comment: It's probably your RabbitMQ version being not recent. Could you check if `rabbitmqctl --help` lists the command `authenticate_user`?

Answer (score 5):

using Python:

```
>>> import pika
>>> URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2F'
>>> parameters = pika.URLParameters(URL)
>>> connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
>>> connection.is_open
True
>>> connection.close()
```